# Digital Audio Resolution and Downsampling

Tags: c++, audio, byte, wav, truncate

I can't figure out this behavior in c++. What trying to modify the gain of the audio by doing the following:

1. Load in a wav file - this works, and i can play the audio correctly from it.
2. Iterate through the data chunk of the file. For every sample, multiply every value by a number, say 0.2. Enough to change the sample, but not enough to overflow the original bit-depth. It's fine if the rounding forces most samples to 0 for this.
3. Save the new value back into the data chunk.

Here is the relevant code:

```
#include <iostream>



int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    FILE* file = fopen(filename.c_str(), "rb+");
    if (file == NULL) return 1;
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    _size = ftell(file);
    char* _data = new char[_size];
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    int bytes_read = fread(_data, sizeof(char), _size, file);
    fclose(file);

    _header = (WaveHeader*)_data;
    _bytesPerSample = _header->bitsPerSample / 8;   

    for (int i = 44; i < _size; i += _bytesPerSample) {

        int sampleValue = readSample(i, bytesPerSample);
        int newValue = sampleValue * 0.01; // Ignoring the glaring truncating and rounding problems here
        memset(&_data[i],0, bytesPerSample); // Trying everything, just in case
        writeSample(i, newValue, bytesPerSample);
        int check = readSample(i, bytesPerSample);
        if( check != newValue) {
            std::cout << "Mismatched value. Expected " << newValue << ", actual " << check << std::endl;
        }
     }
}
```

Here are the read/write sample methods. It may be possible to use casting to write the value instead of using these read/write methods, but i'm not aware of any 3-byte int types in c++.

```
// Samples are in little-endian
int readSample(const int position, const int sampleSize) {
int result = 0;
for (int n = sampleSize; n >= 0; n--)
  result = (result << 8) + _data[position + n];
return result;

void writeSample(const int position, const int value, const int sampleSize) {
memcpy(&_data[position], &value, sampleSize);
```

This *almost* works. What happens is that the check value has the lower bytes correct, but the upper bytes are the same as the original value.
`Original: -3813, Modified: -38, Checked: -294`
Using bitset to check it out, I see that

```
Original: 10011100111101111001111  
Checked:  10011011000000100111101  
Modified: 11111111000000100111101
```

I have no idea why the bottom 2 bytes of "checked" are correct, and the top one is somehow unchanged.

EDIT: The error was here:

```
for (int n = sampleSize; n >= 0; n--)
  result = (result << 8) + _data[position + n];
return result;
```

This is reading one too many bytes, it should be

```
for (int n = sampleSize-1; n >= 0; n--)
```

Comment: Need more info. For example, what is `sampleSize`?  What happens to `result`? How is it used? ... Is `int` 64 bits or 32?... Post a [MCVE].

Comment: If sampleSize is 3, why readSample() reads 4 bytes?

Comment: What's inside _data[]? signed chars or unsigned chars? Are you properly sign- or zero-extending them in the process of combining into an int?

Comment: @JiveDadson i updated the code sample. result is returned in read sample, read sample is called in the loop. int is 4 bytes.

Comment: Try to post a [MCVE], preferably one that is not tangled up with .wav files.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze - Good question. They better be unsigned chars, eh?

Comment: The pity is, I once wrote code for reading and writing .wav files, but I lost it.

Comment: @JiveDadson I appreciate your help. I'm sure you'll find that if you load the program, compile, and pass in your filename of choice, you can recreate that problem. Alexy, you were right. I missed that i'd put >= in the read sample, I was reading a byte too many. That was it

Comment: Let's back up. Change the question to one about reading and writing little-endian values of a specific size (32 bits, I think it is). Factor that part out of your program, and use it in a [MCVE].  All it needs is how to manipulate the data in memory. No file I/O.

Comment: How can I load and compile a code snippet that begins with `assert`?

Comment: Ah. I see you and the rubber ducky worked it out. `for (int n = sampleSize-1; n >= 0; n--)`  I was going to suggest that. That's why I asked what sampleSize was.  Sometimes a literal is better than a name.

Comment: Thank you, Jive. It's actually 24 bits. If we're going to be pedantic, the article specifies: Make sure all information necessary to reproduce the problem is included. I think you'd agree that the way the file is read (perhaps using r instead of rb), forgetting to memset, dirty reads and writes, indexing, casting, and many other things could be factors. Again, thanks for your help. For future reference, you probably only need to include the link once.

Comment: Did I include it twice? I have a short memory. Glad we and the rubber duck were able to help.

Comment: I still don't know what sampleSize is. It would be great if you could post the whole thing. I would appreciate it very much. Like I said, I lost the one I wrote, and I miss it.

Comment: Hello?  I won't say the MCVE thing again, but it would be really, really great, for me and for future generations of stack-overflowers, if the code in the question would compile. As is, the question and 
 its resolution have value to one person only.

Comment: Wrapped it in main, just for you jive. Sample size can be whatever you want it to be, depends on your wav file. Wav header info can be found at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757712(v=vs.85).aspx.

Comment: I tried compiling it. Nine errors. Even `writeSample` and `readSample` are undefined. I may try fixing it later.  If I do, I will edit the question.  Best wishes with your project.